# Connecting to Heroku Postgres Database takes a long time

Tags: heroku

connecting to a Heroku Postgres database using Dbeaver client to after enabling ssl and using  `org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory` takes about 4-5 minutes to connect to the database.

Is this behavior normal?

Answer (score 1):

Just uncheck "Show non-default databases".

It crashes / freezes because it tries to load a huge amount of databases in that host

[image: dbeaver uncheck]

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not normal at all. Connecting should be quite instantaneous. A few seconds is already way too long, and minutes is completely off, so something else is going on.

If you try connecting with some other tool (like `psql` directly), do you have the same problem? I'd check there to make sure your code or some dependency is not doing something odd.